# Ember Select populated by other Ember Select not updating selection binding

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to Ember.js and I'm trying to figure out how Select views bind their selection to the controller. I have this template:

```
{{view Ember.Select
  contentBinding="content"
  selectionBinding="selectedCompany"
  optionLabelPath="content.name"}}


{{view Ember.Select
  contentBinding="selectedCompany.employees"
  selectionBinding="selectedEmployee"
  optionLabelPath="content.name"}} 


Employee: {{selectedEmployee.name}}
Age: {{selectedEmployee.age}}
```

I find that the second select does update when `selectedCompany` changes, but I can't reference the values of `name` or `age` in `selectedEmployee` until I change the second select's value to a different value physically.

How do I make it so that the `selectedEmployee` is set when the first select changes, such that I can use it's value?

For better clarity, I have my working code [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ucEDiDEg/1/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing content of second selectbox does not actualy change its selection. You have to do it manually, for example by adding following method to controller

```
onChangeCompany : function() {
    if (!this.get('selectedCompany.employees').contains(this.get('selectedEmployee'))) {
      this.set('selectedEmployee', this.get('selectedCompany.employees').objectAt(0));
    }
}.observes('selectedCompany')
```

It stil needs some non-null and array-range checking, but does the job - if you select an employee and then change company, employee will change as well.

Comment: This makes sense, but doesn't seem to work. `null` gets returned by the `objectAt` method for some reason instead of returning the first form, which I thinks is causing the problem. The `get` employees seems to work as it returns a promise array, but I don't know how to retrieve values from it.

Comment: If `selectedCompany.employees` is not loaded yet, `objectAt(0)` would be undefined. You have to call the function once more when array loads, so add this array's contents to observed properties: `.observes('selectedCompany', 'selectedCompany.employees.@each')`.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. This seems to tie in with making the models' relationship asynchronous. Adding in the second observed property resolves this, thank you.